# Add new object to JSON automatically

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

So basically, I'm working on this project for frontendmentor and I wanted to go a bit further and make it so this shows stored tasks as well as add new ones.

```
// JSON.data
[
    {
        "name": "task1",
        "todo": "Complete online Javascript course"
    },
    {
        "name": "task2",
        "todo": "Jog around the park 3x"
    }
]
```

```
// Script
getData = () => {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==200) {
            const myData = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
            dataUse(myData)
            saveData(myData)
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "data.json", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

dataUse = (object) =>{
    object.forEach((datas)=>{
        const todo = document.createElement('div')
        todos.appendChild(todo)

        const input = document.createElement('input')
        input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox')
        input.setAttribute('id', datas.name)
        input.setAttribute('class', 'checks')
        todo.appendChild(input)
        
        const label = document.createElement('label')
        label.setAttribute('for', datas.name)
        label.setAttribute('class', `${datas.name} tasks`)
        todo.appendChild(label)
        
        const span = document.createElement('span')
        label.appendChild(span)
        
        const paragraph = document.createElement('p')
        paragraph.innerHTML = datas.todo
        label.appendChild(paragraph)
    })
}

getData()
```

Currently the code above loads the data and then proceeds to make the element needed and place the info in the right place.

What I need now is to make it so it saves a new object to JSON file (when the input has a value(I think I can figure this part myself)) automatically and then proceeds to show it just like the dataUse function does.
This is what I tried to do:

```
let newData = {
    name: "task3",
    todo: "Water the plants"
}

const fs = require('fs')

const saveData = (object) =>{
    const finished = (error)=>{
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
            return
        }
    }

    object.push(newData)

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)
    fs.writeFile('data.json', jsonData, finished)
}
```

This doesn't seem to work but when I try pushing the newData without attempting to rewrite the file and console.log it it does show all the objects including the new one. So how do I make this work? or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `fs.appendFile`

```js
fs.appendFile("data.json", jsonData, finished);
```

I have a repo that uses this general format for reference: https://github.com/cireneirbo/iCanRead-iCanWrite-imFS/blob/main/main.js

Comment: I don't it's the use of append or write that is the issue. The issue is that the function isn't doing anything. Also appending it just adds it to the file, it's suppose to be inserted inside the array.